# Range is not incrementing

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a VBA code that copies cell data from excel sheet and pastes it in powerpoint but I am not able to increment the cell by column-wise like A2, B2, C2, D2 up to U2 and I am new to VBA, people kindly sort this code

I wanted to increment the cells but range is not changing after for loop please kindly look into it

````
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = False
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\point.xls", True, False)
SheetName = activesheet.Name
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

Dim abc As String
'Dim SheetName As String
Dim TestRange As Range
Dim TestSheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteRange As Boolean
Dim RangePasteType As String
Dim RangeName As String
Dim AddSlidesToEnd As Boolean
Dim shts As Worksheet
Dim sld As Slide
Dim grpItem As Shape
Dim shp As Shape
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim a() As Variant
i = 0
   ReDim a(5)
   a(0) = "VNL"
   a(1) = "ABHI"
   a(2) = "ABI"
   a(2) = "RM"


'cell number used
'PasteRange = True
'RangeName = ("B3:B3")
'RangePasteType = "HTML"
'RangeLink = True

AddSlidesToEnd = True

On Error Resume Next
Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0


'Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Make the instance visible
'ppApp.Visible = True

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes

For Each c In Range("A2:A2")
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            abc = c
            For i = 0 To 3
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, a(i), abc)
            Next
    End If

End If
Next c
Next shp
Next
End Sub ```
````

Comment: change `Range("A2:A2")` to `Range("A2:U2")`

Comment: changed sir but they are copying only one cell and pasting on all variables from a[0] to a[4]

Comment: "For Each c In Range("A2:A2")":You've put an Excel VBA line in the middle of a set of PowerPoint statements. PowerPoint wiull try to interpret it and fail. I'm guessing "c" is supposed to be a cell, but you never declare it as such. It's easier to specify cells programmatically is you use R1C1 references instead of A1.